can't move the robot model in gz sim using teleop twist keyboard
Im using ubuntu 24.04.1 ROS2 Jazzy
even if i remap the teleop twist keyboard by cmd_vel:=/diff_drive_controller/cmd_vel
it is still not moving. can someone help me
thanks
ros2_control.xacro
   <?xml version="1.0"?>

<xacro:unless value="$(arg use_ros2_control_gz_sim)">
    <ros2_control name="RobotSystem" type="system">
        <hardware>
            <plugin>diffdrive_arduino/DiffDriveArduinoHardware</plugin>
                <param name="left_wheel_name">left_wheel_joint</param>
                <param name="right_wheel_name">right_wheel_joint</param>
                <param name="loop_rate">30</param>
                <param name="device">/dev/ttyUSB1</param>
                <param name="baud_rate">115200</param>
                <param name="timeout_ms">1000</param>
                <param name="enc_counts_per_rev">616</param> 
        </hardware>
        <joint name="left_wheel_joint">
            <command_interface name="velocity">
                <param name="min">-10</param>
                <param name="max">10</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="right_wheel_joint">
            <command_interface name="velocity">
                <param name="min">-10</param>
                <param name="max">10</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        </joint>
    </ros2_control>
</xacro:unless>

<xacro:if value="$(arg use_ros2_control_gz_sim)">
    <ros2_control name="bot_ros2_control" type="system">
        <hardware>
            <plugin>gz_ros2_control/GazeboSimSystem</plugin>
        </hardware>
        <joint name="left_wheel_joint">
            <command_interface name="velocity">
                <param name="min">-10</param>
                <param name="max">10</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="right_wheel_joint">
            <command_interface name="velocity">
                <param name="min">-10</param>
                <param name="max">10</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>
    </ros2_control>
    
    <gazebo>
        <plugin filename="gz_ros2_control-system" 
            name="gz_ros2_control::GazeboSimROS2ControlPlugin">
            <parameters>
                $(find bot)/config/controller_gz_sim.yaml
            </parameters>
            <parameters>
                $(find bot)/config/gz_ros2_control.yaml
            </parameters>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>   
</xacro:if>

sim.launch.py
    import os
    from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
    from launch import LaunchDescription
    from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription, GroupAction,                    RegisterEventHandler, DeclareLaunchArgument
    from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessStart
    from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
    from launch_ros.actions import Node
    from launch_ros.parameter_descriptions import ParameterValue
    from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, Command
    def generate_launch_description():
    package_name= 'bot'
    package_dir= get_package_share_directory(package_name) 

# Add launch configurations
use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')
use_ros2_control = LaunchConfiguration('use_ros2_control')
use_ros2_control_gz_sim = LaunchConfiguration('use_ros2_control_gz_sim')

# Declare launch arguments
declare_use_sim_time= DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'use_sim_time',
    default_value='true',
    description='If true, use simulated clock'
)

declare_use_ros2_control = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'use_ros2_control',
    default_value='true',
    description='If true, use ros2_control'
)

declare_use_ros2_control_gz_sim = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'use_ros2_control_gz_sim',
    default_value='true',
    description='If true, use ros2_control in gz_sim'
)

# Declare the path to files
robot_description_xacro_file = os.path.join(
    package_dir,
    'description',
    'robot.urdf.xacro'
)

world_file_path = os.path.join(
    package_dir, 
    'worlds', 
    'obstacle.sdf'
)

rviz_config_file = os.path.join(
    package_dir, 
    'config', 
    'sim_config.rviz'
)

robot_controllers_file = os.path.join(
    package_dir, 
    'config', 
    'controller_gz_sim.yaml'
)

gazebo_params_file = os.path.join(
    package_dir, 
    'config', 
    'gz_params.yaml'
)

twist_mux_params_file = os.path.join(
    package_dir, 
    'config', 
    'twist_mux.yaml'
)

bridge_params = os.path.join(
    package_dir,
    'config',
    'gz_bridge.yaml'
)

# robot_state_publisher setup    
robot_description_config = Command ([
    'xacro ', 
    robot_description_xacro_file, 
    ' use_ros2_control:=', 
    use_ros2_control,
    ' use_ros2_control_gz_sim:=',
    use_ros2_control_gz_sim,        
    ])

params = {
    'robot_description': ParameterValue(robot_description_config, value_type=str), 
    'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,        
}

# robot_state_publisher node
node_robot_state_publisher = Node(
    package='robot_state_publisher',
    executable='robot_state_publisher',
    output='screen',
    parameters=[params]
)

# gz_bridge node
# format: '<topic_name>@/[/]<ros2_topic_type_name>@/[/]<gazebo_topic_type_name>',
# ros2 topic type <topic_name> to check topi type_name in ros2
# gz topic -t <topic_name> -i to check topic type_name in gazebo
node_gz_bridge = Node(
    package='ros_gz_bridge',
    executable='parameter_bridge',
    arguments=[
        '--ros-args',
        '-p',
        f'config_file:={bridge_params}',

    ],
    output='screen'
)

# gz launch world
gazebo = IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                get_package_share_directory('ros_gz_sim'),
                'launch',
                'gz_sim.launch.py'
            )]), 
            launch_arguments=
            {'gz_args': f'-r -v 4 {world_file_path}',
             'extra_gazebo_args': '--ros-args --params-file' + gazebo_params_file}.items()
)

# gz spawn robot entity 
node_gz_spawn_entity = Node(
    package='ros_gz_sim',
    executable='create',
    output='screen',
    arguments=['-topic', 'robot_description', 
            '-name', 'minibot',
            '-allow_renaming', 'true',
            '-z', '0.1'],
)

# rviz2 node
node_rviz2 = Node(
    package='rviz2',
    executable='rviz2',
    name='rviz2',
    arguments=['-d', rviz_config_file],
    parameters=[{'use_sim_time': True}],
    output='both'
)

# controller spawn 
joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
    package="controller_manager",
    executable="spawner",
    arguments=["joint_state_broadcaster"],
)

diff_drive_controller_spawner = Node(
    package="controller_manager",
    executable="spawner",
    arguments=["diff_drive_controller", 
               "--param-file", 
               robot_controllers_file
               

    ],
)

node_twist_mux = Node(
    package="twist_mux",
    executable="twist_mux",
    name='twist_mux',
    parameters=[
        twist_mux_params_file,
        {'use_stamped': True},
    ],
    remappings=[
        ('cmd_vel_out', 
         'diff_drive_controller/cmd_vel'),
    ],
)

node_twist_stamper = Node(
    package="twist_stamper",
    executable="twist_stamper",
    name='twist_stamper',
    output='screen',
    remappings=[
        ('cmd_vel_in', 'cmd_vel_smoothed'),
        ('cmd_vel_out', 'nav_vel'),
    ],
)

register_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
    event_handler=OnProcessStart(
        target_action= node_gz_spawn_entity,
        on_start= [joint_state_broadcaster_spawner],
    )
)

register_diff_drive_controller_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
    event_handler=OnProcessStart(
        target_action= joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
        on_start= [diff_drive_controller_spawner],
    )
)

group_spawn_gz= GroupAction(
    [gazebo, 
     node_gz_spawn_entity,
    ]
)


# Create the launch description and populate
ld = LaunchDescription()

# Add the nodes to the launch description
ld.add_action(declare_use_sim_time)
ld.add_action(declare_use_ros2_control)
ld.add_action(declare_use_ros2_control_gz_sim)

ld.add_action(register_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner)
ld.add_action(register_diff_drive_controller_spawner)

ld.add_action(node_robot_state_publisher)
ld.add_action(node_twist_mux)

ld.add_action(node_twist_stamper)
ld.add_action(node_gz_bridge)

ld.add_action(group_spawn_gz)
#ld.add_action(node_rviz2)

# Generate the launch description  
return ld


It looks like you may have accidentally created two accounts (koaellie & Koa Ellie). Stack Exchange only allows an individual to actively use one account, so please follow the instructions at I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?
Note that moderators can't merge accounts for you.

Have you set stamped parameter of teleop_twist_keyboard to true?
ros2 run teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard --ros-args --remap cmd_vel:=/diff_drive_controller/cmd_vel -p stamped:=true

From jazzy on, diff_drive_controller uses only TwistStamped instead of the unstamped one.
